# JavaFX key events for child element

Tags: java, events, javafx

I'm trying to handle KeyEvents in a child element, however its not working.

My Scene:

```
...
public void initScene(){
    ...
    root =  new Group();
    mainScene = new Scene(root);
    mainScene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent arg0) {
            if(arg0.getCode()==KeyCode.ESCAPE){
                System.out.println("escape");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else if(arg0.getCode()==KeyCode.BACK_QUOTE){
                if(Variables.DEBUGGING)
                    DebugWindow.changeVisibility();
            }

    });
}
...
public void replaceContent(Parent temp){
    root.getChildren().remove(1);
    root.getChildren().add(temp);
}
...
```

And my child element in another class:

```
...
public void initAnotherPanelInAnotherClass(){

    root = new Group();

    root.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if(arg0.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY){

            GuiApp.replaceContent(SettingsWindow.getInstance().getContent());

            Debugger.println("Window changed.");
            }
        }

    });

    //THIS EVENT IS NOT FIRED
    root.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent arg0) {

            Debugger.println("Something happend.");
            //Nothing happen:(      
            }

    });
}
```

The code is working fine, my Scene's KeyEvents working (ESC and back quote), the content gets replaced on click (so ClickEvent in the child is working too), my Debugger also writes out everything. Except that KeyEvent in the child element is not fired.

Is there any way that my Scene events and the Scene's root KeyEvents working together?

Comment: Is your child element [focusTraversable()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusTraversableProperty)?  Does it have focus or has [focus been requested](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#requestFocus%28%29) for it?

Comment: If the answer to the focus questions is yes, and you still have an issue, edit your post to create a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  So that the issue can be easily replicated, ensure that you can copy and paste your example for compilation and execution without any code modification.

Comment: Maybe you should use `addEventFilter` and catch the `KEY_RELEASED` during event capturing phase?