# Continue loop with enter

Tags: loops, javafx, enter

So i'm working on a JavaFX project in which i have loop, which i want to continue only if the enter is pressed. Since i'm working it with scenes and it's javafx i do not want to use scanner method (because i can't, or can i ?)  which wants the input to be entered into console not in the game frame.

I searched the web but the only way i found was to do it with scanner and that does not work. Is there any other possible way to do this or use scanner somehow.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992606/javafx-key-events-for-child-element). You probably should attach a KeyEvent listener and updade yor state which will cause the loop to continue. Note that the loop in this case shoul run in separate thread.

Comment: I read another thread which said that i should never pause a loop to wait for an event. So i modified my code that it will work with a button and everything went fine. But thanks for help